# Loading JSON data into QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, json

How do you load data like this into QGIS?

```
{
 "href": "https://mapservices.crd.bc.ca/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/Basemap/Basemap_MapServer/_ags_map47050197f6f7491b88c00c386e0c7d6a.png",
 "width": 400,
 "height": 400,
 "extent": {
  "xmin": 452274.18156210636,
  "ymin": 5351125.3209655574,
  "xmax": 460539.78142663941,
  "ymax": 5359390.9208300905,
  "spatialReference": {
   "wkid": 26910,
   "latestWkid": 26910
  }
 },
 "scale": 78099.999999999913
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For the **Capital Regional District** (CRD) Basemap you can use:

```
https://mapservices.crd.bc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/
```

In QGIS you can use the ArcGIS Rest Services Connection.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It depend what you are trying to do. GeoJSON data can be added to QGIS by saving your data as a .geojson file and simply dragging and dropping the file onto the map canvas, but this *must* be geographic data. (See here for valid geojson files: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON)

In your case, you might not need to do that - you are able to load the image in the href link by:

1. Saving the image to your computer > Dragging and dropping the saved image file into QGIS
2. Going to the layer CRS settings for the new layer
3. Setting a coordinate reference system for the new layer (in your case, 26910).

[image: Workflow for adding png image to qgis]